# Magnifier icon in nave bar when I hover I wantit to be the same size as other navbar links size

Tags: search, hover, icons, size, navbar

I was wondering what is wrong with my search icon in nav bar When I hover over it its padding is too small, and when I increase padding, the whole navbar size increases, what do I do?

Thanks....

code if u need it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Just put padding inside link tas not search icon.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).